# Catch statement in a different method is being executed instead of the catch in the method where the exception was thrown Java

Tags: java, exception

This is a strange issue, especially since I am not great with try-catch statements. I have one method called getMove() that ensures a move is legal before passing it to the makeMove() method. I also have a method called playMode() that lets a player choose which game type they want to play. I have a try-catch that checks for InputMismatchException in the playMode() method to ensure players are not entering letters, when only numbers are allowed. In the getMove() method I also have an InputMismatchException to check for the same thing. Players are only allowed to enter numbers, not letters.

The playMode() method works great, but whenever I use the getMove() method and an exception is thrown, it sends the user all the way back to playMode. Please give me any help you can :).

Here is my getMove() method :

```
 public static int[] getMove(char[][] board) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter the X coordinate of your move : ");
    int x = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Please enter the Y coordinate of your move : ");
    int y = in.nextInt();
    boolean needsRerun = true;
    while (needsRerun) {
        try {
            while (x != 0 && x != 1 && x != 2) {
                System.out.println("Invalid move");
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print("Please enter the X coordinate of your move : ");
                x = in.nextInt();
            }
            while (y != 0 && y != 1 && y != 2) {
                System.out.println("Invalid move");
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print("Please enter the Y coordinate of your move : ");
                y = in.nextInt();
            }
            while (board[x][y] != ' ') {
                System.out.println("Invalid move. Someone has already played here.");
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print("Please enter the X coordinate of your move : ");
                x = in.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Please enter the Y coordinate of your move : ");
                y = in.nextInt();
            }
            needsRerun = false;
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid move. Try again.");
            getMove(board);
        }
    }

    int[] move = {x, y};

    return move;
}
```

And here is my playMode() method :

```
public static void playMode() throws InterruptedException {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("If you would like to play against another player, press 1 : ");
    System.out.println("If you would like to play against the AI, press 2 : ");
    int playMode = 0;

    while (playMode != 1 && playMode !=2) {
        try {
            playMode = in.nextInt();
            if (playMode == 1) {
                playerVsPlayer();
            }
            if (playMode == 2) {
                playerVsAI();
            }
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid entry. Try again : ");
            playMode();
        }
    }
    if (playMode == 1) {
        playerVsPlayer();
    }
    if (playMode == 2) {
        playerVsAI();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems.

Firstly, in getMove(), the calls to nextInt() that initialize variables 'x' and 'y' are not within the scope of the try/catch block, so any exceptions from nextInt() will always propagate outtwards.

Secondly, if you get past those, but hit one of your 'invalid move' cases and then the user gives non-numeric input - then you'll throw an exception which will be caught.  *The non-numeric input remains unread*.

You then recursively call getMove(), and the bad input data will cause the nextInt() that initializes 'x' to fail.  This time you have no exception handler in getMove() to handle  it.  The handler for the innermost call is not yet in effect; the handler for the outermost call is already executing.  Thus the exception propagates outward.

Thirdly, the recursive call made from the exception handler, even if successful, does not terminate the loop in the outermost call.   You'd loop and validate the input that was already validated in the inner call (if we didn't have the bug described under 'secondly').  I can't figure out what your thinking is here.  There's a strange mix of recursion and iteration, either of which would be sufficient in itself if carried through properly.

Lastly, your recursive call to getMove() ignores its return value, and then returns the invalid x,y coordinates, so that's going to fail as well.  But I think that's a 'future' problem, not the one you've found so far.